# Problem capturing RGBDSLAM pointcloud data in headless mode

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, pcd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Third RGBDSLAM question of the day... sorry :-)

In order to speed up processing (and hence hopefully improve mapping significantly) I'm running RGBDSLAM in headless mode. So, I'm trying to try generate a new .pcd file using the following command:

**roslaunch rgbdslam headless.launch**

(not *roslaunch rgbdslam rgbdslam_headless.launch* as it says in the README)

I then, in a different Terminal, execute:

**rosservice call /rgbdslam/ros_ui_b pause false**

to start to "capture a stream of data:" and the RGBDSLAM Terminal displays:

*[ INFO] [1328358771.842035641]: Pause toggled to: false*

However, the CPU load does not increase at this stage as I expected. I then try to save the pointclouds as a singe pcd file by executing:

**rosservice call /rgbdslam/ros_ui save_all**

But no file is generated and the RGBDSLAM Terminal displays:

*[ INFO] [1328358846.008384132]: Saving Whole Model to quicksave.pcd*

*[ INFO] [1328358846.008732434]: Saving all clouds to quicksave.pcd, this may take a while as they need to be transformed to a common coordinate frame.*

***[pcl::PCDWriter::writeBinary] Input point cloud has no data!***

***[ INFO] [1328358846.008925177]: **Saved 0 data points to quicksave.pcd***

Am I going about this in the correct way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12886/problem-capturing-rgbdslam-pointcloud-data-in-headless-mode/) by [Mike Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/1677/mike-moore/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Mike. Could you please copy the following line into headless.launch, so that it is enclosed in the  tag.

```
<param name="config/store_pointclouds" value="true"/>
```

Storing the pointclouds for sending them out later is convenient, though it requires a lot of memory.
If you want significant improvements of quality, I'd suggest to look at the file rgbdslam_sample_config.launch. It should contain all parameters that influence accuracy and speed (mostly in tradeoffs one vs the other). If you have a GPU, try SIFTGPU feature detector and extractor to speed things up.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I too had the same problem I tried Above solution too but could not SOLVE the problem.

The solution I found is,

You should launch openni_node before running headless.
i.e.

> roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch

and then

> roslaunch rgbdslam headless.launch

---

Originally posted by [sunilsulania9192](https://answers.ros.org/users/748/sunilsulania9192/) with karma: 224 on 2012-06-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-07-09**:
Yeah, of course the camera driver needs to be running.